# Dynamically set element width based on ng-repeat item count

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I am new to use AngularJS 1.4.x .

```
<div class="colContainer" ng-repeat="item in betNumber" ng-style="{width:{{rowWidth(item.length)}} +'px'}">
```

when press AddNumber ball more then 13 ,i wish width size can resize .
This is my hope
[image]

i hope can dynamic change div width size ,how to let it work fine ???

This is my hope http://plnkr.co/edit/t8bBjE?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `ng-style` value to
`{width:rowWidth(item.length) +'px'}`. That should work.

The `ng-style` directive will evaluate the whole object, which means it will use the `$parse` method to evaluate the expression. So you don't have to use double curly braces.

Comment: If you think this answer solved your problem, please accept my answer. Thank you.